# How to display the same video in multiple TextureView?

Tags: android, exoplayer, textureview

I'm using ExoPlayer to play a MPEG-DASH stream video. I need to set this video into multiple TextureView, then crop these views at different positions. Is it possible, and how can I do that?
Thanks very much.

Comment: `"... then crop these views at different positions."` - what do you mean by that?

Comment: @pskink oh I mean I want to display only a piece of video in each view. I want to crop this video screen to 4 pieces, and display each piece in one view.

Comment: see `TextureView#setTransform()` method

Comment: Oh thanks @pskink I will learn about it. How about the first point - set the video player into multiple views ? Do you have any clue?

Comment: you need to have 4 players imho

Comment: Yeah I've thought about it. But it's not display contemporaneous, though that's what I need. Moreover, this is stream video, so I think that using multiple players also adversely affect to perfomance. So I'm looking for a better solution.